# Find a quantity that is constant along the solutions of the ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following problem.

> Find, for any $r > 0$, a quantity that is conserved along the
>   trajectories of the system $\ddot{x} = r - e^x$

How do I exactly solve this question?

I had a question which is more or less the same

> Find a function that is constant along the solutions of the second
>   order differential equation $\ddot{x} + \cos(x) = 0$.

which I solved as below. The problem is more or less that I don't know if this is correct...

$\ddot{x} + \cos(x) = 0 \Leftrightarrow \ddot{x} = -\cos(x)$. Now let $y = \dot{x}$ and $\dot{y} = \ddot{x}$, so $y$ is the position and $\dot{y}$ is the velocity. Now we define the Hamiltonian function as the sum of the potential energy and the kinetic energy e.g. $H(x) = P(x) + K(x)$. The derivative of the potential function should be equal to $y = \dot{x} = \sin(x)$. Hence

$$\frac{\partial P(x)}{\partial y} = \sin(x) \Rightarrow P(x) = \int \sin(x)\mathrm{d} y = \sin(x)y = \sin^2(x)$$

$$\frac{\partial K(x)}{\partial \dot{y}} = -\cos(x) \Rightarrow K(x) = -\int \cos(x) \mathrm{d}\dot{y} = -\cos(x)\dot{y} = \cos^2(x)$$

Hence $H(x) = \sin^2(x) + \cos^2(x) = 1$. Thus for the time derivative we have (I write the third = part for clearance of the variables)

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}H(x(t))}{\mathrm{d}t} = \frac{\partial H}{\partial x} \dot{x} + \frac{\partial H}{\partial y} \dot{y} = \frac{\partial H}{\partial x} \dot{x} + \frac{\partial H}{\partial \dot{x}} \ddot{x}$$

Now $\frac{\mathrm{d}H(x(t))}{\mathrm{d}t} = 0$ since $\frac{\partial H}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial H}{\partial y} = 0$. Hence $H$ is constant along solutions.

Comment: What does $r$ have to do with the first ODE?

Comment: $$\ddot{x}(t) - f(x(t)) = 0
\quad\implies\quad \frac{d}{dt}\left[\frac12 \dot{x}^2(t) - \int^{x(t)} f(y)dy\right]
= \dot{x} (\ddot{x} - f(x) ) = 0$$

Comment: @Amzoti sorry that was a typo. The $1$ had to be a $r$.

Comment: @achillehui I am not sure how that would help me?

Comment: Take $f(x)$ as $r - e^x$, we have
$$\begin{align}
\ddot{x} - (r - e^x) = 0 
\implies & \frac{d}{dt} \left[ \frac12 \dot{x}^2 - (rx - e^x) \right] = 0\\ 
\implies & \frac12\dot{x}^2 - (rx - e^x) = \text{constant along a trajectory}\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More generally, the ODE $\ddot x = -\nabla U(x)$ (where $x$ may be a vector) describes the motion of a unit point mass under conservative force with potential $U$. The  total energy, kinetic + potential, is conserved. Indeed, 
$$\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac12 \dot x^2+U(x) \right) = \ddot x \dot x + \nabla U(x) \dot x = 0$$
In your case, we need $U'(x)=e^x-r$, which leads to $U(x)=e^x-rx$, and to the conserved quantity 
$$\frac12 \dot x^2+e^x-rx$$
which   was given by achille hui.